# Set layout = 'Fit' to tab item

Tags: extjs, grid, tabpanel, extjs6

I have a tabpanel as follows-

```
 var topTab = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
      region: 'center'
 });
```

I am adding tab items on click of a button

```
 topTab.add(someGrid);
```

this works well. Only the issue is, this grid is not getting fit into the tab item. I want to set layout = 'fit' to this tab.

I tried adding

`topTab.items[0].setLayout` but it is not working. Also tried giving height to the grid.

Any suggestions. **(Using ExtJs 6)**

Comment: Tab panel uses a card layout (which extends fit), so all items will automatically fit. Post a test case.

Comment: Is there any way I can apply this manually... like `topTab.items[0].layout = 'fit' ` Something like that?

Comment: Your `setlayout` has multiple issues. First JavaScript is case-sensitive, second, [`setLayout`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1-classic/Ext.container.Container.html#method-setLayout) has a big marker: **"NOTE: this method cannot be used to change the "type" of layout after the component has been rendered to the DOM"** For further suggestions, more details are needed.

Comment: Read what I said above. Tab panels automatically fit child items to their size. You need to post a test case.

Comment: If I cannot change layout after rendering of component, then where should I set `layout : 'fit'`

Comment: I will create a fiddle. But my grid is not automatically fitting into the tab item

Comment: Which is why you're creating a fiddle, because the issue is likely elsewhere in the code.